# check for spacing or - in a text filed

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a check for empty spacing or - character in a textfield.
I can use this for -

```
function isValid( str ){
   var is_valid = true;
  if(str.indexOf('-') === -1){
     is_valid = false;
  }
  return is_valid;
}
```

but I want to combine a method that checks for multiple - and empty spacing between characters.

Example someone could enter a string like this. var str = "emp t y"
I want to check if the empty space are present or if they do something like this.
var str = "12-34-55"

Comment: why do you need to check for multiple, would the number of spaces or dashes greater than 1 determine if it is valid? What do you want to do if multiple are found?

Comment: You are right it really doesn't matter I guess. If one is found then it would be an error.

Comment: Where is the empty space check in the regex /[-\s]/g I see -

Comment: @user1096509 `\s` accounts for multiple types of whitespace

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
function isValid( str ){
    return !(/-|\s/.test(str));
}
```

[Simple JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4krAn/).

References:

- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`RegExp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Comment: This is always returning true for me. I have a string like this. var str = "100 200 - 1" this should return false but it returns true.

Comment: Then you've got something else going wrong, because it works for me: [representative demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4krAn/1/).